# Missing cross-selling and related products option in admin

Tags: magento-1.8, backend, related-products, up-sells, cross-sells

I notice in several websites about Magento mentioning the "Related Products", "Up-Sells" and "Cross-Sells" options in the admin backend under the "Manage Products" section.

However, when I log into my Magento backend, I could only see the "Up-Sells" option. The other two options, "Related Products" and "Up-Sells" are missing from the menu.

How can I get "Related Products" and "Up-Sells" options to show up on in the admin backend?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Catalog > Product` and open any product. You can find "Related Products", "Up-Sells" and "Cross-Sells" options in left side tabs.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Related & Crossale]

In Product Page Here you can see Related & Cross-sells Product in Magento.